# how to allocate pointer to pointer on stack and how on heap?

Tags: c++, pointers, heap-memory, stack-memory

Is this correct way to allocate pointer to pointer on stack and on heap? If not, then what is a correct way to do it?

```
int a=7;
int* mrPointer=&a;
*mrPointer;

int** iptr; // iptr is on stack
*iptr=mrPointer; //not OK
int** iptr_h = new int*(); // iptr_h is on heap
*iptr_h=mrPointer;
```

---

thanks to Mat's answer now I know that this is correct way to put it on stack:

```
int** iptr; // iptr is on stack
iptr=&mrPointer;
```

and this on the heap:

```
int** iptr_h = new int*(); // iptr_h is on heap
*iptr_h=mrPointer;
```

Comment: At the point `*iptr=mrPointer;`, `iptr` is uninitialised, so dereferencing it is undefined behaviour.

Comment: What makes you think there is a right way to allocate a pointer to a pointer in C++? Instead of asking the right way to do this, you should ask about the right way to accomplish something (and this probably won't be the right way to do it).

Comment: Yes, I do believe this is an "XY question" - you think Y is the solution to achieve X, so you ask how to do Y. It may be better to ask "How do I achieve X". It may not be a double pointer in the first place...

Comment: no, I am interested in how to allocate pointer to pointer on stack and how on heap, and do it correctly, this is all

Comment: Question is worded strange.  One could interpret it such that you want to allocate a pointer-to-a-pointer on the heap.  To me, that means you want to allocate storage for `int**`, meaning you will get a pointer to that memory which will be a `int***` which you will then store on the stack.  The other interpretation is that you want to allocate a pointer on the heap and store a pointer-to-a-pointer on the stack.

Comment: Why would you put a pointer to a pointer on the _heap_?  Why would you have a pointer to a pointer?  In C++ the only time you should see `**` is in comments, or when interfacing with C or legacy code.

Comment: why would you declare constructor private?

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain I don't think you meant to post that here.

Comment: @Mooing Duck you are wrong

Comment: @restart.localhost.localdomain: In that case, what are you talking about?  Nobody has said the word "constructor" nor "private" nor anything even remotely vaguely related except for you.  Wait, are you just asking a completely unrelated question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want a pointer to pointer that eventually points at the `a` variable, then this is how you do that.

```
int a=7;
int* mrPointer=&a;
*mrPointer;

int** iptr; // iptr is on stack
iptr=&mrPointer;
```

Edit: to clarify, in the above code I changed `*iptr = mrPointer;` to `iptr = &mrPointer;`.

This will indeed make a pointer to the same place, via the heap.

```
int** iptr_h = new int*(); // iptr_h is on heap
*iptr_h=mrPointer;
```

Edit to explain based on comment:

One could also see a need to do something like this:

```
int* mrsPointer;
int** iptr = &mrsPointer;
*iptr = mrPointer;
```

Comment: this is it, thanks, I omitted the fact that I cant do *iptr because it was uninitialized, but if it was then *iptr=mrPointer is correct there, right?

Comment: @Mats: you put on the heap a pointer to an int.  I kind of think he wants to put on the heap a pointer to a pointer to an int.  `int*** iptr_h = new int**(&mrPointer);`

Comment: no, I wanted pointer to int to be put on heap. This is exactly this what I wanted

Answer (score 1):

When you allocate space for the object using `malloc` or `new`, it will always end up on the heap. You may use `alloca` for stack allocations, but this is significantly more advanced and not recommended.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, and the use of `malloc` is shunned in C++.

Comment: I answered 'how to allocate on stack/heap'. I included `malloc` to be complete, which is not irrelevant since many C++ projects interface with C.

Comment: yes, I changed question latter to reflect comments/advices other participants